# How to clear all rows from a TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, tableview

I know that this has already been asked before, but none of the other responses have helped me, so I'll ask myself...

I am trying to delete all my existing rows from a `TableLayout` because I want the user to be able to update the table dynamically. Other suggestions have recommended using `removeAllViews()`, which is supposed to remove all child views, however this deletes rows from my other tables in the same `LinearLayout` (I have a linear layout with multiple tables).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It sounds like you might be calling `removeAllViews()` on the whole `LinearLayout` and not the particular `TableLayout` you want to clear. Double check you have some thing like:

`myLinearLayout.someTableView.removeAllViews()`

Comment: Nope, I'm definitely calling my TableLayout...

  tl = (TableLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.afi_waist_table);
  tl.removeAllViews();

Comment: Changed my code around a bit and was able to get removeAllViews() working.

Comment: Calling removeAllViews() actually worked fine. I thought it was deleting my other tables' content because I was using a TableRow for the table header, which I didn't think I had done.

Answer (score 14):

You need to call removeAllViews() on each TableRow:

```
int count = table.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    View child = table.getChildAt(i);
    if (child instanceof TableRow) ((ViewGroup) child).removeAllViews();
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion will remove all the subviews of the row but not the row itself. The table layout will be left with empty rows.

Comment: I know, that's what I thought the original poster wanted.

Comment: great! this is fine for me :D

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove all the rows but the first row (which is often used as the header), you can use:

```
tableLayout.removeViews(1, Math.max(0, tableLayout.getChildCount() - 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `yourTableView.removeViews(startIndex, count)`
***startIndex*** is an integer value for where you want to start removing. Incase you have an header and don't want to remove it, start at position 1, otherwise start at 0. 
***count*** is the number of row to remove.