# dynamic tablelayout in android in whice the rows should be cleared for before the start of next iteration

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have created a dynamic `TableLayout` in my android app  in which the rows changes for every iteration. For first iteration it show up data from XML response and for second iteration it has to show up only the updated XML response. But in my case it is taking data from iteration 1 _iteration.  How to clear table rows before next iteration starts to load in android

Comment: i mean showing up old table data along with new table data. need to show only the latest table data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7302733/4491971) as a reference.

You can call `removeAllViews()` method on the `TableLayout` object.
For example, `tableLayout.removeAllViews()`.

Comment: Thanks @Janani. Can you please Upvote the answer too.